# filename with space are not opening in html links

Tags: php

function to display list of files. this code is to display the list of files in a folder/directory in a tabular format. list of displayed files are to be clickable. output is coming but file name having any gap in between are not opening on click.  instead i tried this line  in above code instead but still not opening and display of file name also looks odd as '%20' is added wherever space found in the filename.  please suggest.

```
function outputFiles($path) 
    {
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path))
    {
        $result = scandir($path);
        $files = array_diff($result, array('.', '..'));

                  // output file list in HTML TABLE format
                  echo "<table align=center border=\"1\">\n";
                  echo "<thead>\n";
                  echo "<tr><th>Filename</th></tr>\n";
                  echo "</thead>\n";
                  echo "<tbody>\n";
                  foreach($files as $file) 
                  {
                    echo "<tr>\n";
                    echo "<td><a href=$path/$file>".basename($file)."</a></td>";
        // echo "<td><a href=$path/$file>".rawurlencode($file)."</a></td>";  tried this also
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                  }
                  echo "</tbody>\n";
                  echo "</table>\n\n";
    } else 
    {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the `href` value inside quotations. It is always good practice to put any tag attribute in quotations. So just change

```
<a href=$path/$file>
```

to

```
<a href='$path/$file'>
```

or

```
<a href=\"$path/$file\">
```

---

The problem is when you have space in filename, lets say the file name is `foo bar` and you write

```
<a href=$path/$file>
```

it'll become

```
<a href=foo bar>
```

which actually means the value of `href` attribute is `foo` and we have another attribute called `bar`, but when you write

```
<a href='$path/$file'>
```

it'll become

```
<a href='foo bar'>
```

which means the value of `href` attribute is `foo bar`.